# EF Core SingleOrDefaultAsync compile time return type error

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write an async method that returns a single object from EF core in my repository. I have the following method:

```
public async Task<Administrator> GetOne(Guid guid)
{
    var admin = await _ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Guid == guid);
    return admin;
}
```

However this give the following compile time error:

> Cannot convert expression type TResult to return type Administrator

If I change it to the following code (i.e. no OrDefault) I get no issues:

```
public async Task<Administrator> GetOne(Guid guid)
{
    var admin = await _ctx.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Guid == guid);
    return admin;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also a second point, is the code correct in the first place or should I just be returning the result without an await i.e.

```
public Task<Administrator> GetOne(Guid guid)
{
    return _ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Guid == guid);
}
```

Comment: You are missing type cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to solve your compilation error :

> I change it to the following code (i.e. no OrDefault) I get no issues.
>
> What am I doing wrong?

You should try the following to force the compiler to convert the return Type values *and* the possible default (null) type to `Administrator`

```
 ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Guid == guid) as Administrator;
```

Note :

The above code return null if there is a user with the provided id but it cannot be converted to an Administrator instance.

If you want an exception to be thrown in this case, you can use a 'classic' cast :

```
 (Administrator) ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Guid == guid);
```

---

### About 'await' or 'not await'

> Also a second point, is the code correct in the first place or should I just be returning the result without an await

My guess is that **you want to await your code here**. Ultimately, only you really know, but I can't see any abvious reason not to do so, and many reason to do await it.

If you don't `await`, then you get a Task out of your function, possibly not completed yet, while the rest of your calling code probably depends on the actual `Administrator` result.

Comment: Tthank you the first suggestion solved it. FYI, the second option didn't work.

Comment: I edited my question to provide another way, that is slightly different (other kind of cast)

Comment: That is all really helpful and I've been able to go through and refactor a lot of code because of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This method signature : `public async Task<Administrator> GetOne(Guid guid)` should return a  `Task<Administrator>`.

The `ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync` call isn't returning a `Task<Administrator>`.

As for your second point: If you don't need the result just return the `Task`.